# Virtualbox 5.1 OSE with PUEL version

Tags: virtualbox

I removed traces of Virtualbox and reinstalled Virtualbox 5.1 from the website. However, I keep getting this error message.

[image]

I don't know what else I can possibly do and I already ran `/sbin/vboxconfig` and that ran with no problems. So I don't see why I'm still getting this error message. Can someone help?

Currently this is what I get

```
yann@Milvia:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox         0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1  all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virtualbox-5.1                 5.1.14-112924~Ubuntu~xenial  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
yann@Milvia:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  unity-scope-vi 0.1+13.10.20 all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
un  virtualbox     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.14-11292 amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-qt  5.0.32-dfsg- amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt 
yann@Milvia:~$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia-375, 375.26, 4.4.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.26, 4.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Thanks.

Comment: From the `terminal`, show me the output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`

Comment: `ii  virtualbox-5.1                 5.1.14-112924~Ubuntu~xenial  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox`

Comment: How did you "removed traces of Virtualbox". Did you use the standard methods of uninstalling software, or did you manually go-a-hunting? Your error suggests that there's more VB software than just the 5.1.14 that you're showing. Show me the full output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and `dkms status`, and edit the output into your question, not in comments.

Comment: Okay updated the question.

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-qt` and then `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and make sure that the "rc" changes to a "un" on the virtualbox-qt line. Then test and see if you still have that error.

Comment: ps: you also have two `dkms` problems... "(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)". Start a new question for that, and include the `dkms status` command output.

Comment: Still getting the same error when I run virtualbox.

Comment: How did you remove older/other versions of VB? Update your `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` in your question.

Comment: ps: did you install the latest VB Expansion Pack in VB 5.1.14?